# Typescript: class implements interface issue?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript 2.5.2 following does not work:

```
interface I {
    m?():void;
}

class C implements I {
}

let c = new C();
c.m();  <== Error : TS2339:Property 'm' does not exist on type 'C'.
```

Why is the `m` method not found?

If I add:

```
interface C extends I {}
```

It's ok! Or if I add:

```
let c = new C() as C & I;
```

It's ok too.

As I understand `implements` should combine `C` and `I` types as C & I.
Is it an issue?

Comment: Interfaces are implemented abstract classes are extended.  Interfaces are just a contract saying that any methods are going to be supported in the actual class. You need to implement m in class C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface you have is a weak type that doesn't enforce the property `m` on implementers.

TypeScript is smart enough to see that `m` is definitely not on your class, but you can prevent the error by asking TypeScript to treat the variable as the interface:

```
let c: I = new C();
c.m();
```

Despite this trick, you'll still have a runtime problem, which TypeScript tried to warn you about.